# Problems while posting values to web service

Tags: android

I have a web service written with web api. I am posting from android to the web service. But unfortunately am getting errors. I am sure of my web service code. But I dont know why my android code is just not posting values. MY web service code is below.

```
  [HttpGet]
    public EmergencyOccurenceModel RegisterEmergency(EmergencyOccurenceModel model){

       int result = this.webserviceModules.RegisterEmergencyOccurence(model);

       if (result > 0)
           model.OccurenceType = "success";
       else
           model.OccurenceType = "failed";

        return model;
    }



 public class EmergencyOccurenceModel
{     
    public string OccurenceType { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; } //This is going to store the location of the accident

    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Then my android code is pasted below

First is the object used when sending to web api

```
public class EmergencyOccurenceModel {

   private String OccurenceType;

   private String Address; //This is going to store the location of the accident

   private String State;

   public void setOccurenceType(String  OccurenceType){

       this.OccurenceType =  OccurenceType;
   }

   public String getOccurenceType(){

       return OccurenceType;
   }

   public void setAddress(String Address){

       this.Address = Address;
   }

   public String getAddress(){

       return Address;
   }

   public void setState(String State){
       this.State = State;
   }

   public String getState(){

       return State;
   }


   //This strings below would be used to form the json annotations to collect values from the web service
   public static String EmergencyOccurenceModel_OccurenceType="OccurenceType";
   public static String EmergencyOccurenceModel_Address = "Address";
   public static String EmergencyOccurenceModel_State="State";
```

}

The AnsycTask Class that does the posting

```
 class ReportEmergencyOccurence extends  AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

     private Context context = null;
     private String OccurenceType  = null;
     private ProgressDialog progressdialog = null;
     private String Address = null;
     private String loadMsg = null;
     OnTaskCompleted listener = null;

     EmergencyOccurenceModel model = null; EmergencyOccurenceModel ReturnValue = null;

     public ReportEmergencyOccurence(OnTaskCompleted listener,Context context, String OccurenceType,String loadMsg,String Address){
         this.listener = listener;
         this.context = context;
         this.OccurenceType = OccurenceType;
         this.Address = Address;
         this.loadMsg = loadMsg;

     }


     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute(){
         super.onPreExecute();

         progressdialog= new ProgressDialog(context);
         progressdialog.setMessage(loadMsg);
         progressdialog.show();
     }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            model = new EmergencyOccurenceModel();
            model.setOccurenceType(OccurenceType);

            if(OccurenceType.equals("Accident"))
                model.setAddress(Address);
            else
                model.setAddress(Address);

            model.setState("Lagos");

            Log.i("values",model.getAddress());
            Log.i("values",model.getOccurenceType());
            Log.i("values",model.getState());


            JSONHttpClient jsonHttpClient = new JSONHttpClient();



            ReturnValue = (EmergencyOccurenceModel)jsonHttpClient.PostObject(RestfulServiceUrl.ReportEmergency, model, EmergencyOccurenceModel.class);

            return null;
        }



     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String s){


         if(ReturnValue != null){

             if(ReturnValue.getOccurenceType().equals("success"))
                 this.listener.onTaskCompleted("success");  
         }
         else{               
             this.listener.onTaskCompleted("failed");
         }


         this.progressdialog.dismiss(); //This is going to close the progress dialog             
     }


 }
```

Then the logcat error message

```
09-17 09:22:24.681: W/KeyCharacterMap(448): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
09-17 09:22:24.801: D/dalvikvm(448): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 97K, 46% free 3050K/5575K, external 2284K/2734K, paused 63ms
09-17 09:22:26.771: I/values(448): 13, Ibarapa street, ebute metta west
09-17 09:22:26.771: I/values(448): Accident
09-17 09:22:26.771: I/values(448): Lagos
09-17 09:22:27.861: I/jsonobject(448): org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@40546520
09-17 09:22:28.051: D/dalvikvm(448): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 139K, 46% free 3187K/5831K, external 1572K/2071K, paused 42ms
09-17 09:22:28.201: D/AndroidRuntime(448): Shutting down VM
09-17 09:22:28.201: W/dalvikvm(448): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-17 09:22:28.201: E/AndroidRuntime(448): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 09:22:28.201: E/AndroidRuntime(448): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 09:22:28.201: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at com.example.jadehealthcare.EmergencyActivity$ReportEmergencyOccurence.onPostExecute(EmergencyActivity.java:182)
09-17 09:22:28.201: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at com.example.jadehealthcare.EmergencyActivity$ReportEmergencyOccurence.onPostExecute(EmergencyActivity.java:1)
09-17 09:22:28.201: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
09-17 09:22:28.201: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
09-17 09:22:28.201: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
09-17 09:22:28.201: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 09:22:28.201: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-17 09:22:28.201: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
```

Comment: What is there in Line No. 182?

Comment: what is line 182 at EmergencyActivity

Comment: is your ReturnValue.getOccurenceType() != null?

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String s){ - It is complaining of the values returned on from the web service. When I check my web service db I notice that no values was stored   @Hardy

Comment: But my question is does it really connect to the webservice. If it does why is it not storing values in the database. cause I check my db logic and it is correct. I ran a test script to saved into the db and it worked well.

Comment: @MemLeak  ReturnValue is null for some reasons I dont understand. it is really surprising to me cos I am sure that my post contains values. if you see this in my log cat.                            09-17 09:22:26.771: I/values(448): 13, Ibarapa street, ebute metta west
09-17 09:22:26.771: I/values(448): Accident
09-17 09:22:26.771: I/values(448): Lagos

Comment: it throws exception because of that null return value, you should return at least an empty string

Comment: From my web service I am returning the object I sent. Under normal circumstance It should not be null.

Comment: 09-17 09:22:27.861: I/jsonobject(448): org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@40546520.  Does this line confirm a successfull connection to my webservice. @user2754532

Comment: From all I see it looks like connection to the webservice is not successful but the line above makes me feel it is. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Your server waits for a "[HttpGet]" and you do a httpPost? May be you should expect a HttpPost. As far as i kow, its not possible to post an object via get, you vould parametrize and pass the object.

Comment: Thanks alot you are the boomb, I have check for hours and I did not see this. Men you have the eye of an eagle. Let me compile my code again. @MemLeak

Comment: Problem solved !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!. Woooooooooow MemLeak you made my day. You are the best. you really have a very special eyes. Men I can't believe I did not see this. I have battled over this since yesterday nite. Thanks God Bless you. @MemLeak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in Comment (again so its "acceptable"):
Your server waits for a "[HttpGet]" and you do a httpPost? May be you should expect a HttpPost. As far as i kow, its not possible to post an object via get, you vould parametrize and pass the object.